# How to pass fill colors to recharts Pie component

Tags: reactjs, recharts

So basically i have this array of objects:

```
const testMeasurments = [
  {
    data: [
      {name: "glucose", value: 6, color: '#57c0e8'},
      {name: "SpO2", value: 5, color: "#FF6565"},
      {name: "Blood Pressure", value: 4, color: "#FFDA83"},
      {name: "Body Weight", value: 2, color: "purple"}
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to loop over them and access the `color` property. So basically i have a chart and each part will have its own color so I want to loop inside the object while assigning the value also to assign the color to it.

Example:

```
{testMeasurments.map(s=>
        <Pie 
        dataKey="value" 
        isAnimationActive={false} 
        data={s.data} 
        cx={200} 
        cy={200} 
        outerRadius={100} 
        innerRadius={60}
    fill={s.color} // Here I want to loop over each color and assign it to the proper value
  >
```

As you can see it is certainly not working here but thats what i need! Thank you in advance.

Comment: how do you pass testMeasurments?

Comment: what is `props` and `props.data`?

Comment: @Oyeme sorry for the inconvenient please refer to the fixed code

Comment: @RedBaron sorry for the inconvenient please refer to the fixed code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the [code example for the Pie component](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/blob/master/demo/component/Pie.js), you need to rename the `color` property to `fill` in your data set, and then it will automatically work. The `fill` property on the `Pie` component is for the component-level filling color.

```
const testMeasurments = [
  {
    data: [
      {name: "glucose", value: 6, fill: '#57c0e8'},
      {name: "SpO2", value: 5, fill: "#FF6565"},
      {name: "Blood Pressure", value: 4, fill: "#FFDA83"},
      {name: "Body Weight", value: 2, fill: "purple"}
    ]
  }
]

/// ...

{testMeasurments.map(s=>
        <Pie 
        dataKey="value" 
        isAnimationActive={false} 
        data={s.data} 
        cx={200} 
        cy={200} 
        outerRadius={100} 
        innerRadius={60}
        fill="#fff"
  >
```

Comment: waw i didn't know that! thank you so much it worked perfectly

Comment: I don't understand how this works? as fill will be `#fff` everytime wont it? but I thought the OP wanted it to be the value of the colour property?

Comment: @RedBaron because the OP tried to set the wrong property. But s/he wanted to set the fill colors for the individual data points, not for the whole pie chart component.

Comment: @viam0Zah i am sorry i didn't accept it earlier but on that day they told me you cannot accept the answer right away so i forgot to do it later sorry! again thank you for your answer

Answer (score -1):

try something like this:

```
testMeasurments.map((tm) => {
   return tm.data.map((data) => {
       <Pie 
         dataKey="value" 
         isAnimationActive={false} 
         data={data.data} 
         cx={200} 
         cy={200} 
         outerRadius={100} 
         innerRadius={60}
         fill={data.color}
   })
}
```

Comment: `data.data` is referring to a not existing property. Only `tm` has `data` attribute.

Comment: yeh I wasn't sure what it was so left it as that, sure the OP could fix it though as necessary

Comment: this way your solution will create a pie chart for each data point instead of showing the data set on a single one. I don't think it's what the OP wanted to achieve.

Comment: yeh I think yours is correct but OQ was slightly confusing

Answer (score -1):

If you are passing `testMeasurements` as a prop, then you need to take the first element of the `testMeasurements` array and then you can access the `data` array and then you can loop over like this -

```js
{
    this.props.testMeasurements[0].map(dataSet => (
        <Pie
         dataKey="value" 
         isAnimationActive={false} 
         data={dataSet.data} 
         cx={200} 
         cy={200} 
         outerRadius={100} 
         innerRadius={60}
         fill={dataSet.color}
        />
    ))
}
```

Comment: I believe `testMeasurments` will contain more than one measure so hard-coding for the first element doesn't seem a generic solution. Also, in your solution, `dataSet` has no `data` property.